Modifying ol3-search-layer functionality in an OpenLayers map exported from QGIS2web
I have a mapping project to document my tree collection at https://whisperingweevil.com/map/map.html
I am using QGIS and QGIS2web to generate code for my web map. I have a search field to search the column of my attribute file that contains information about the "Type" of tree and the search currently returns all of the matching trees of that type in a dropdown. So if I search "Hickory" all of the different types of Hickories appear in a list below the search field.
I would like to adapt the search function to return the information from the first column of the attribute file "Cultivar" when I search the second column of the table "Type". So, when I search "Hickory" the dropdown should list all of the corresponding cultivars of hickory starting with 'Grainger' rather than 'Shagbark Hickory'. I have been looking through the code of my ol3-search-layer.js file to try to figure out how to adapt the code, but I am coming up short. I am a novice at coding, so I am not sure where to start. My ol3-search-layer.js file is the standard output from QGIS2web:
function hasClass(el, cls) {
  return el.className && new RegExp('(\\s|^)' +
    cls + '(\\s|$)').test(el.className);
}

function addClass(elem, className) {
  if (!hasClass(elem, className)) {
    elem.className += ' ' + className;
  }
}

function removeClass(elem, className) {
  var newClass = ' ' + elem.className.replace(/[\t\r\n]/g, ' ') + ' ';
  if (hasClass(elem, className)) {
    while (newClass.indexOf(' ' + className + ' ') >= 0) {
      newClass = newClass.replace(' ' + className + ' ', ' ');
    }
    elem.className = newClass.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
  }
}

var SearchLayer = (function (Control) {
 function SearchLayer(optOptions) {
  var horseyComponent;
  var select;
  var options = optOptions || {};
  if (optOptions.layer) {
    options.layer = optOptions.layer;
  } else {
    throw new Error('error');
  }
  options.map = optOptions.map;

  var source;
  if (options.layer instanceof ol.layer.Image &&
      options.layer.getSource() instanceof ol.source.ImageVector) {
    source = options.layer.getSource().getSource();
  } else if (options.layer instanceof ol.layer.Vector) {
    source = options.layer.getSource();
  }
  options.colName = optOptions.colName;

  var button = document.createElement('button');
  var toogleHideShowInput = function() {
    var input = document.querySelector('form > .search-layer-input-search');
    if (hasClass(input, 'search-layer-collapsed')) {
      removeClass(input, 'search-layer-collapsed');
    } else {
      input.value = '';
      addClass(input, 'search-layer-collapsed');
      horseyComponent.hide();
      select.getFeatures().clear();
    }
  };

  button.addEventListener('click', toogleHideShowInput, false);
  button.addEventListener('touchstart', toogleHideShowInput, false);

  var form = document.createElement('form');
  form.setAttribute('id', 'random');
  form.onsubmit = undefined;
  // form.setAttribute('action', 'javascript:void(0);');

  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.setAttribute('id', 'ol-search-input');
  var defaultInputClass = ['search-layer-input-search'];
  if (optOptions.collapsed) {
    defaultInputClass.push('search-layer-collapsed');
  }
  input.setAttribute('class', defaultInputClass.join(' '));
  input.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Search ...');
  input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
  form.appendChild(input);

  var element = document.createElement('div');
  element.className = 'search-layer ol-unselectable ol-control';

  element.appendChild(button);
  element.appendChild(form);

  ol.control.Control.call(this, {
    element: element,
    target: options.target
  });

  select = new ol.interaction.Select({
    id: options.selectId || 'defaultSearchLayer',
    layers: [options.layer],
    condition: ol.events.condition.never
  });

  var map = options.map;

  map.addInteraction(select);

  var typesToZoomToExtent = [
    'MultiPoint',
    'LineString',
    'MultiLineString',
    'MultiPolygon',
    'Polygon'
  ];

  var typesToZoomToCenterAndZoom = [
    'Point'
  ];
  var returnHorsey = function(input, source, map, select, options) {
    horsey(input, {
      source: [{
        list: source.getFeatures().map(function(el, i) {
          if (el.getId() === undefined) {
            el.setId(i);
          }
          return {
            text: el.get(options.colName),
            value: el.getId() // If GeoJSON has an id
          };
        })
      }],
      getText: 'text',
      getValue: 'value',
      predictNextSearch: function(info) {
        var feat = source.getFeatureById(info.selection.value);
        var featType = feat.getGeometry().getType();
        if (typesToZoomToCenterAndZoom.indexOf(featType) !== -1) {
          var newCenter = ol.extent.getCenter(feat.getGeometry().getExtent());
          map.getView().setCenter(newCenter);
          map.getView().setZoom(options.zoom || 12);
        } else if (typesToZoomToExtent.indexOf(featType) !== -1) {
          map.getView().fit(feat.getGeometry().getExtent(), map.getSize());
        }

        select.getFeatures().clear();
        select.getFeatures().push(feat);
      }
    });
  }
  if (source.getState() === 'ready') {
    horseyComponent = returnHorsey(input, source, map, select, options);
  }
  source.once('change', function(e) {
    if (source.getState() === 'ready') {
      horseyComponent = returnHorsey(input, source, map, select, options);
    }
  });
 };
    if (Control) SearchLayer.__proto__ = Control;
    SearchLayer.prototype = Object.create(Control && Control.prototype);
    SearchLayer.prototype.constructor = SearchLayer;
    return SearchLayer;
}(ol.control.Control));


my attribute file looks like this:
var json_Trees_1 = {"type":"FeatureCollection","name":"Trees_1","crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"}},"features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"fid":"1","Cultivar":"Rhodes","Type":"Heartnut","Date_Graft":"2014-06-01","Date_Bear":"2018-10-01","Image":"D:/Downloads/rhodes.jpg","Rootstock":"Black Walnut","Treatments":null,"lat":40.0,"long":-82.0},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-82.0,40.0]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"fid":"2","Cultivar":"Warren","Type":"Pecan","Date_Graft":"2023-05-01","Date_Bear":null,"Image":"D:/Downloads/warren 346 pecan.jpg","Rootstock":"Northern Pecan","Treatments":null,"lat":40.0,"long":-82.0},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-82.0,40.0]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"fid":"3","Cultivar":"T-92","Type":"Hican","Date_Graft":"2023-05-01","Date_Bear":"2019-11-10","Image":"D:/Downloads/T-92.jpg","Rootstock":"Northern Pecan","Treatments":"Treated with 2+ ml of Tuber lyonii slurry 10/14/23","lat":40.0,"long":-82.0},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-82.0,40.0]}}

If someone could kindly direct me to the code that I need to change, that would be a fantastic help!

creating a third column that adds the data of the first and second and then setting this in the search could solve the problem?

From the user point of view this does not make much sense. User types something but sees something completely different. Both columns should be displayed

Creating a third column is a good solution. Thanks for the idea!

Not at all. Please consider donating a virtual coffee via the github homepage to support the development of qgisweb. Thank you.
